# How can i change classname values dynamically base on if the id of data i'm mapping is Odd or Even? in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Goodday everyone, i have list of text and images in a div, i used flex display and flex direction row for each div, however, during the mapping of this data, if the id is odd number, i want to reverse the flex row, if it's even number it should not reverse, that way one div will have image right side, and the other will have image left side

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { UiData } from "./UiDesignData";

function UiComp({ text, imageUrl, imgUrl }) {
  const [toggleClass, setToggleClass] = useState(false);

  const handleToggle = () => {
    setToggleClass(!toggleClass);
    // console.log(ids);
  };

 

  return (
    <div className="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row col-12 UIs align-items-center justify-content-between">
      <div className={UiData.indexOf % 3 === 3 ? "flex-row-reverse " : " "}>
        {" "}
        <p> {text} </p>{" "}
      </div>
      <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-end ImgCon col-12 col-md-6">
        <div className={toggleClass ? "ImgHoverM " : "ImgHovers"}>
          <img src={imageUrl} alt="" className="col-8" />
        </div>
        <img src={imgUrl} alt="" className="col-12" />
        <div className="TapView">
          <button id="UI1" onClick={handleToggle} className="text-center">
            {" "}
            Tap to View{" "}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default UiComp;
```

Example:
[image: Example output]

Comment: Why are you checking if id is odd or not with `%3`? and if you take modulus of 2 then output will be 0, 1 and not 2 i.e. modulus of n will give output from 0 to n-1. You condition of `%3===3` won't be true.

Comment: I was just trying things around, what did initially was " UiData.id % 2 === 0" as you can see now, it's indexOf that i have there, i was just trying different things since my initial approach didn't work

Comment: It would be insightful if you add your `UiData` also in code snippet to get idea of data and it's type. And [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) returns the index of element